# Why does this for loop return a different sized list than expected?

Tags: python, numpy, spotipy

I'm doing a data analysis project using spotipy and numpy libraries. I've figured out how to achieve my expected result, but I don't know exactly **why** a slight change (using a for loop) to my code causes it to not work. here is my code:

```
def get_user_playlist(username, playlist_id, sp):
    offset=0
    playlist_songs = sp.user_playlist_tracks(username, playlist_id, limit=100, fields=None, offset=offset, market=None)['items']
    
    return playlist_songs

def create_dataframe(playlist_songs):
    
    playlist_df_columns = ['artist','track_name','id','explicit','duration','danceability','loudness','tempo']
    
    #audio_analysis_columns = ['danceability','loudness','tempo']
    playlist_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_columns)
    # song = dict object containing song
    
    playlist_df['artist'] = np.array([song['track']["album"]["artists"][0]["name"] for song in playlist_songs])
    playlist_df['track_name'] = np.array([song['track']['name'] for song in playlist_songs])
    playlist_df['id'] = np.array([song['track']['id'] for song in playlist_songs])
    playlist_df['explicit'] = np.array([song['track']['explicit'] for song in playlist_songs])
    
    
    for song in playlist_songs:
        
        audio_analysis = sp.audio_features(song['track']['id'])
    
    #returning audio_analysis for testing purposes.
    return audio_analysis
    #return playlist_df
```

the important part is the for loop, when I run this code, the length of the `audio_analysis` list = 1 :

```
for song in playlist_songs:
        audio_analysis = sp.audio_features(song['track']['id'])
```

However, it works when I **remove** the for loop and do this instead, the length of the `audio_analysis` list = 94, as expected.:

```
audio_analysis = sp.audio_features(playlist_df['id'])
```

For reference, here is the code that prints the length:

```
playlist = get_user_playlist('username', 'playlist_name', sp)
audio_analysis = create_dataframe(playlist)
print(len(audio_analysis))
```

My question is: why does the for loop not work as I expect? Is my code not accessing the same information? Why isn't using a for loop to access information the same as using the `playlist_df['id']` column directly?

Comment: Each time through the loop you're replacing `audio_analysis`. So at the end it just contains the value from the last song.

Comment: The second version is creating a df that contains values from every song in `playlist_df`

Comment: Oh yeah!!! I just changed it now so it appends to a list each time and it works! It's much slower to run though. Thanks a lot :) Hope you have a great day! @Barmar